# XML Timezone remove

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt

I have a Date coming from SQL 2010-05-11 10:30:00 But when i applyc XSL it is adding the 2010-05-11T10:30:00-04:00 time zone offset. Is there any way we can remove that from XSL.

Comment: What functionality are you using to format the date?

Comment: It would be a little bit easier if you provided a input example.

Answer (score 1):

Use substring to format?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" />
     <xsl:template match="*">
          <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
               </xsl:for-each>
               <xsl:apply-templates />
          </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="MyMessage/DateField">
          <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,4)"/>
               <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,5,2)"/>
               <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,7,2)"/>
          </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```